# Как работает OpenThemeAction?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, dll

В библиотеке `themecpl.dll` есть функция `OpenThemeAction`, которая вызывается виндой при запуске файла `*.theme`. Но данная функция после применения темы открывает окно настроек, чего я хочу избежать. Что именно эта функция использует для изменения темы и можно ли изменить тему вручную? Что-то вроде:

```c
#include <windows.h>

void ApplyTheme(LPWSTR lpszThemeFile){
    //???
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow){
    ApplyTheme(L"C:\\Test\\my.theme");
}
```